# Emulator won't shutdown - Windows XP

Tags: android

Windows XP.  Experienced Java developer.  Just started with Android development.  Emulator (started with Eclipse, NetBeans or command line) works properly until I try to close it.  Then, it hangs and the workstation must be rebooted.  Some observations and data: java is version 1.6.0_23-ea. The emulator shows as 'Not responding' in the task manager.  Every time the emulator is started, it always has two entries in the task manager.  If the emulator was started from command line, the command box is also frozen.  Have tried different avds, always the same.  Eclipse and NetBeans are both the latest version.  Cannot stop the emulator from the task manager or Control-C in the command dialog.  The rest of the workstation continues to respond (mostly) but can send nothing to the emulator.  The workstation can not be rebotted, it must be powered off and powered on.

Anyone have any ideas?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar Java-related issue with a totally different thing. Are you using a 32 bit JVM on a 64 bit machine? (you are using XP so I presume you're not 64bit...) Just a hint...

Comment: No, I am using 32\bit JVM on 32bit XP.  Do have plenty of memory (2.5GB free.)  Thanks for the idea.